# SVN não verifica alterações do Branch

Tags: visual-studio, versionamento, svn

Eu criei um branch a partir do trunk, e fiz todas as alterações necessárias.
Quando finalizei as alterações, usando Visual Studio 2015 eu mesclei o branch com o trunk.

Eu estava resolvendo os conflitos quando me equivoquei na escolha de um deles.
Fiz o revert na solution para mesclar novamente tudo, porém, dessa vez, o Visual Studio ou o próprio SVN não "encontra" nenhum commit pendente, é como se estive mesclado tudo.

Quando eu abro o branch, eu tenho minhas alterações, quando eu abro o trunk, eu não tenho as alterações, se eu mesclo o branch com o trunk, não há nada pendente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que você pode fazer, é um merge manual caso o seu SVN tenha dado algum bug.

Antes, tente realizar o clean up na trunk e no branch em questão.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso o problema persista, faça uma cópia do branch e cole na trunk, e o efeito será o mesmo, poderá editar os conflitos no commit.

Comment: Tentarei fazer o celan up.
"faça uma cópia do branch e cole na trunk" Como é feito essa operação?

Comment: Copy and Paste normal. Vai no seu branch, copia todos os arquivos e joga na raiz da trunk... Faça o commit e verá todas as alterações. Entendeu?

Comment: Certo, mas e as alterações no turnk que foram feita por outros? Não vou perder?

Comment: não, porque o svn vai identificar as alterações

Comment: Você me salvou amigo. Digo, ainda não sei.
O fato é que quem tentou mesclar pro primeiro foi outro programador.
Antes de eu tentar mesclar, eu fiz um clean up. 
Posteriormente, eu usei outra opção pelo VS para dar merge, diferente da que o primeiro programador usou.
Nesse caso, não sabemos se era a opção diferente que deveria ter sido usada, ou se foi o celan up que corrigiu.

Comment: Que bom que eu te ajudei, fico feliz. Eu já tive problemas em commit com o VS com trabalhos em equipe, eu geralmente uso ele somente quando estou fazendo algo solo, em equipe, uso o próprio SVN. Abraços